# What is ?= in Makefile

Tags: makefile

```
KDIR ?= $(shell uname -r)
```

What is the meaning of `?=`?

I have understood the difference between `:=`, `+=` and `=` from another thread available in Stack Overflow, but unable to find the explanation for `?=`.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

`?=` indicates to set the `KDIR` variable only if it's not set/doesn't have a value.

For example:

```
KDIR ?= "foo"
KDIR ?= "bar"

test:
    echo $(KDIR)
```

Would print "foo"

GNU manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html

Comment: Does it mean that KDIR is already declared somewhere in the system?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, since `?=` can be used to apply a default/fallback value to a variable, it may be allowing `KDIR` to be set in the environment.

Comment: @Simon Note that command line arguments to make already override Makefile variables without the need of `?=`.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to Simon and R.T. for their quick and correct response.

Also, I have found the GNU manual that explains everything in detail:
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html