# Makefile logical AND

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How to perform a logical AND in makefile. if I run `make test` It works as expected
it gives the output `Both PARAMETERS are required`.  If one of the parameter is missing  It should still give the same output but its not working that way for example if I run `make test PARAM1=abc` it should output `Both PARAMETERS are required`.How can I mandate both the parameters.

```
%/test:
    ifeq ($(PARAM1)$(PARAM2),)
        @echo "Both PARAMETERS are required"
        @exit 1
    endif
    @echo "Do Something $(PARAM1) $(PARAM2)"
```

I have tried the below code and it gives the error  *** missing separator.  Stop. I am not familiar with makefile any help is appreciated.

```
%/test: 
    @# $(or $(and $(PARAME1),$(PARAM2)),$(error Both PARAMETERS must be set))   
    @>&2 echo "Do Something $(PARAM1),$(PARAME2)"
```

Comment: You must indent your lines with literal TAB characters, not spaces.  Make sure your editor is not converting TABs to spaces for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test by its very nature checks that the concatenation of the two is the empty string.  If that's not what you want to check, perform a different check. For example,

```
%/test:
    @# $(or $(and $(PARAM1),$(PARAM2)),$(error Both PARAMETERS must be set))
```

Various other variations; [Makefile set if variable is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801796/makefile-set-if-variable-is-empty)

Comment: The code actually has a tab but Stack Overflow renders it as four spaces so you can't blindly copy/paste from here.

Comment: Bug report: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403016/literal-tab-in-code-block-renders-as-four-spaces